# Using COUNT in INNER JOIN in SQLite (to count absent records)

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, count

In SQLite, I have a table named *Items*:

```
| id | name  |
|----|-------|
|  1 | ..    |
|  2 | ..    |
|  3 | ..    |
|  4 | ..    |
|  5 | ..    |
|  6 | ..    |
```

Each item might have tags associated with it. Tags are stored in another table, and have their own IDs. The association of items and tags is stored in a third table called *Associations*:

```
| itemID | tagID  |
|--------|--------|
|      1 |      1 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      1 |      3 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      3 |      4 |
|      3 |      5 |
|      4 |      5 |
```

As you can see, item 1 has 3 tags, items 2 and 4 have 1 tag each, and item 3 has 2 tags. Items 5 and 6 have no tags, so their IDs do not appear in the *Associations* table.

Now, I want to retrieve IDs of items having less than, say, 2 tags, including zero tags. If it were only about the Associations table, the task is easy:

```
SELECT itemID FROM Associations GROUP BY itemID HAVING COUNT(tagID) < 3;
```

But this will not return IDs of items which do not have tags, as they are absent in the *Associations* table. So I guess I have to use JOIN somehow. I tried

```
SELECT id FROM Items INNER JOIN Associations ON Associations.itemID=Items.id GROUP BY itemID HAVING COUNT(Associations.tagID) < 3;
```

But this seems to do the same as the previous query.
Help is appreciated :)

**EDIT:** So, the answer is just to replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY itemID` with `GROUP BY Items.id`.

**QUESTION EXTENDED:** Now, to tell the secret, the tags (apart from having IDs) fall into different categories, say, red, green and blue (so, e.g., red tag with id 5 and green tag with id 5 are in fact different tags).

```
| itemID | tagID  |tagType|
|--------|--------|-------|
|      1 |      1 | red   |
|      1 |      2 | red   |
|      1 |      3 | blue  |
|      2 |      1 | green |
|      3 |      4 | blue  |
|      3 |      5 | red   |
|      4 |      5 | blue  |
```

So I need to retrieve IDs of items which have less than N tags *of specific type*. I thought I could easily solve this by using the Yogesh's answer by adding the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT i.id AS itemID  
FROM Items i LEFT JOIN 
 Associations a 
 ON a.itemID = i.id
WHERE a.tagType='red'
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(a.tagID) < 3;
```

But this again fails to return items which do not have tags at all, because they are now filtered out by the `WHERE` condition. I think I need something along these lines:

```
SELECT i.id AS itemID  
FROM Items i LEFT JOIN 
 Associations a 
 ON a.itemID = i.id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(a.tagID WHERE a.tagType='red') < 3;
```

But this does not seem to be a valid statement. Help appreciated again; I might "reaccept" the answer.

Comment: Use a `left join` instead and `group by items.id` instead of `associations.itemid` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT i.id AS itemID  
FROM Items i LEFT JOIN 
     Associations a 
     ON a.itemID = i.id 
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(a.tagID) < 3;
```

Comment: Finally I found the case where LEFT JOIN is useful :) Thanks.

Comment: I have accepted the answer for now, but now I have extended the question with a bit of complexity, so the question is in fact open again :)

Comment: @Maximko. . . Your question edit would be invalid after accepting the solution, but still i would suggest to ask another question with ref. this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can count in a subquery:

```
select *
from items i
where 2 >
(
  select count(*)
  from associations a
  where a.itemID = i.id
);
```

This gets you all items with less than 2 associations (i.e. zero or one).